# I need this simple repeated words detector explained

Tags: c++

The code works perfectly, but i'm confused on how exactly it works. I can't understand why we need to sort the string vector at all. It would just sort the words alphabetically, right? Also, how can it detect any word and not just adjacent words when we're comparing it to a string variable "Previous"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void detect(vector<string> vs);

int main() {
vector<string> vs;
string current;
while (cin>>current)
    vs.push_back(current);
    sort(vs.begin(), vs.end());
    detect (vs);
    system("pause");
}

void detect(vector<string> vs){
    string previous = " ";
    int index = 0;
    while (index < vs.size()) {
        if (vs[index]==previous) {
            cout<<"repeated words: " <<previous<< endl;
        }
        previous = vs[index];
        index++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the vector is being sorted alphabetically using `sort()`, any duplicate words will be next to one another (since they are the same word and will contend for the same spot in the sort). This way the `detect()` can just look at all pairs of adjacent words and detect duplicates that way. If the vector was not sorted then `detect()` would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Answer1: If it is sorted alphabetically, any equal elements will be next to each-other.

Answer2: It **does** get only equal values adjacent to each-other, but because of the sort all equal values will be adjacent to each-other.

I hope this helps.